# Converting 1OCT20 to Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, series

I have a series of dates but in a format like "1OCT20" or "30MAR19", how can I convert them into datetime?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pd.to_datetime` with the `format` argument set to `%d%b%y`

> #### %d    Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.
>
> #### %b    Month as locale’s abbreviated name.
>
> #### %y    Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.

I usually use this https://strftime.org/ website when looking for specific datetime formats.

```
pd.to_datetime('1OCT20',format='%d%b%y')
Timestamp('2020-10-01 00:00:00')
```

---

```
pd.to_datetime('30MAR19',format='%d%b%y')
Timestamp('2019-03-30 00:00:00')
```

on your dataset you can cast it directly on your column

```
df['trgdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['srcdate'],format='%d%b%y')
```

Comment: Thank you! this is what i was looking for!!

Comment: @Demi you are most welcome, happy coding my friend